# how will i passed the json data into php

Tags: php, json

I have four textboxes and when you click on the add one button it will add up another set of textboxes. My problem is how can i pass the json data to the action form. Here is my code:

```
 $("#test").click(function(){


                 var array = $('.experience').map(function() {
                    var obj = {};
                    $(this).next().addBack().find('input:text').each(function() {
                      obj[this.id] = this.value;
                    });
                    return obj;
                }).get();

                $('#json').text(JSON.stringify(array, null, 2));


            });
```

and my form action

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url().'resume/update'?>" method="post" id="send_form">


 <!-- Experience Start -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <h2>Experience</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row experience">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="resume-employer">Employer</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resumeEmployer" id="resume-employer" value="<?php echo set_value('resumeEmployer'); ?>" id="resume-employer" placeholder="Company name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="resume-experience-dates">Start/End Date</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resumeExperienceDates" name="<?php echo set_value('resumeExperienceDates'); ?>" id="resume-experience-dates" placeholder="e.g. April 2010 - June 2013">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="resume-job-title">Job Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resumeJobTitle" id="resume-job-title" value="<?php echo set_value('resumeJobTitle'); ?>" placeholder="e.g. Web Designer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group" id="resume-responsibilities-group">
                            <label for="resume-responsibilities">Responsibilities (Optional)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resumeResponsibilities" id="resume-responsibilities" value="<?php echo set_value('resumeResponsibilities');?>" placeholder="e.g. Developing new websites">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <hr class="dashed">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <p><a id="add-experience">+ Add Experience</a></p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Experience Start -->
 <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <input type="submit" id="test" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


    </form>
```

i added a id="test" in the input type="submit button

any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: look at .live() or .on() method to register the click that might work in your caase as you are populating text form after DOM is loaded.

Comment: $(#test" ).on( "click", function() {
 ---- your code goes here
}

Comment: can you add some codes on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` and `json_decode` function example in ref link,

```
json_encode($arr);
var_dump(json_decode($json)); 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Comment: yes i know how to use this one but can you modifly your code with my code?